# Обработка CheckBox в ListBox'е

Tags: c#, wpf

Существует ListBox, в котором в StackPanel объедены два элемента: CheckBox и Label. Код:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ANSWListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="180" Margin="340,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" MouseDoubleClick="ANSWListBox_MouseDoubleClick">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
            <Label Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="{Binding Content}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Foreground="White" Width="375"></Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Добавляю в ListBox, использую класс

```
class ANSWBoxTemplate
{
    public bool Itstrue {get;set;}
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

И код:

```
ANSWListBox.Items.Add(new ANSWBoxTemplate() {Content = "Example", Itstrue = false});
```

Вот, что получается в итоге:

[image: Результат]

Мне нужно, что бы по нажатию на CheckBox свойство Itstrue элемента, которому принадлежит CheckBox устанавливалось на значение true. Как это реализовать?

Comment: `Как это реализовать?` - использовать `MVVM`, реализовать `INPC`, создать коллекцию и к ней привязаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну используйте привязку: `IsChecked="{Binding Itstrue}"`

Кстати, чекбокс имеет свойство `Content`, поэтому эта ваша конструкция со `StackPanel` и `Label` не нужна.

Comment: Я почему-то думал, что привязки работают только в одну сторону...

Comment: @SKProCH, ну это поведение настраивается, см. свойство [`Mode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode(v=vs.110).aspx), но по умолчанию для `IsChecked` как раз двухсторонняя привязка